# How to define a exactly match using PHP preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to remove some parameters from a URL using PHP preg_replace(). For example, i need to remove `a[]=1`  from the bellow URL.

```
$my_url = 'www.myhost.com/filter.php?a[]=1&a[]=12&a[]=13&a[]=14'
```

So i am using:

```
$without_filter = preg_replace("/(&)?a\[\]=1/", '', $my_url);
```

I want to remove only `a[]=1`, but it is removing the portion that contains `a[]=1` from the others parameters, so am i getting:

```
www.myhost.com/filter.php?234
```

Someone can help me to solve this?

Comment: you could probably add a `\b` at the end to specify a "boundary" is needed. boundary=non word character or end of line/string.

Comment: for something this specific you can also use str_replace, which is good if it's a static/simple match you're looking to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about: `/a\[\]=1(&|\b)/`

That way it will capture `a[]=1` *only* if it is followed by a `&` or end of string.

Comment: Hmm... say the url is: example.com/abc?foo=bar&a[]=1 then we'll have a trailing & left.

Comment: @songyy, You are wrong, if i have `a[]=12&a[]=1&a[]=13&a[]=14` i will get `a[]=12a[]=13&a[]=14`. Note that `a[]=12a[]=13` don't have the `&` separator, so we will lose its content. The previor answer have a `&` at the end of the string, but it works normally.

Comment: @songyy, If you use the ER `/(&?)a\[\]=1(&|\b)/` you will get this error, so the best ER is `/a\[\]=1(&|\b)/`

Comment: @MarcioSimao Hmm... I agree with you now ;)

Comment: @MarcioSimao Sorry a bit too many comments I'm giving here... I'm thinking then probably just /a\[\]=1(&|$)/ ? Cuz the \b would include chars like '=' also (or other non-word chars)... which might appear in the url

Answer (score 1):

Following the man page of [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) you may do something like this:

```
$without_filter = preg_replace("/\&(a\[\]=1)(\&|$)/", '\2', $my_url);
```

Or... you can always use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: You gave a nice tip, but even remaining a `&` at the end of the string, the URL works in the browser. So i think the @Supericy answer is more simple.

Comment: @MarcioSimao Ahh... I forgot this ~:) Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$limit` parameter of `preg_replace` and set it to `1`, this should replace it only once. Assuming that your parameters are always sorted this way:

```
$without_filter = preg_replace("/(&)?a\[\]=1/", '', $my_url, 1);
```